# Simple HQL Query and Criteria in Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have to write that HQL query:

```
FROM Sending adp WHERE adp.id = (SELECT MAX (adpw.id) FROM Sending adpw WHERE adpw.place = adp.place)
```

I have to use Criteria API and I can't manage it. Query returns last sendings from all places in database and it works very well but now I have to transform it to Criteria. The only thing I managed is to show just one place with following code:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(
                    Sending.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("place", FetchMode.JOIN);
DetachedCriteria maxId = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Sending.class).setProjection(Projections.max("id"));
criteria.add(Property.forName("id").eq(maxId));
```

Could you help me? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What is the problem with the Criteria code you've shown? It doesn't work? It gives wrong results?

Comment: I am recieving just one result. The only one with max id - a sending with max id. And it has to return over 350 - last sending from each place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I found the solution.

I forgot that Subqueries can be correlated with themselves. I realized my query with following code:

```
Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Sending.class);
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Sending.class, "adpw");
dc.add(Restrictions.eqProperty("adpw.place", "adp.place"));
dc.setProjection(Projections.max("id"));
criteria.add(Property.forName("id").eq(dc));
criteria.setMaxResults(count).setFirstResult(start);
return criteria.list();
```

Everything works now very well.